# SassError: Undefined variable: "$main-background-color"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to use CSS-variables during the LoginPage component styling but receiving the following error: 
`SassError: Undefined variable: "$main-background-color".`
This error appears in the `_styles.scss` file.

this is my project structure:

[image: project structure]

I'm importing both `_variables.scss` and `styles.scss` to the main `index.scss` file:

[image: index.scss]

What I'm doing wrong while importing variables? 
Why I can't use them in the `_styles.scss` file?

Comment: Path to the file is wrong from what I can tell here. Should be ../general

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need to import the `_variables.scss` directly into `_styles.scss` if you want to use them there

Answer (score 2):

Is `$main-background-color` your css variable (as in custom property) or did you define it as a Sass variable?

If it is an actual css variable/custom property you need to use it like this: `var(--main-background-color)` and as a global variable it needs to be defined at `:root {}` or any other top element like `<body>` or `<html>`.

If it is a Sass variable you need to make sure which file you're trying to compile. You can't compile `_styles.scss` on its own, it has to be `index.scss` and you need to make sure that your compiler isn't trying to compile modules (files starting with `_`) first as this would of course fail.

The `@import` command basically just copies everything together so loading it in multiple locations would add this multiple times. Sass modules avoid this with heir `@use` command but this is only supported in Dart Sass and not LibSass.